# Apply Promotion to Specific Configurable Product

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions, coupon-codes

I would like to know how to apply `$10 discount coupon code for combination one configurable product and simple product`. Coupon code needs to be `applied for combination of any associated product of the base product` and the another simple product. If I dont include the configurable product for the rule, coupon code is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought a lot about this feature. And now I can offer you a solution.

Create following category tree (don't forget to hide this categories from navigation menu):

```
Default category
|-Discount 1
  |-Product 1
  |-Product 2
  |-Product 3
```

Then create 3 different products and assign them on each category. For example:

> **My simple product** assigned on category **Product 1**
>
> **My configurable product** assigned on category **Product 2**
>
> **My another simple product** assigned on category **Product 3**

Then go to shopping cart price rules and create following condigion:

[image]

Where 4,5,6 are ids of your categories. To apply this condition only on these products on 'Actions' tab choose following:

[image]

The described rule will be applied only on these 3 products and only when they will be together in cart.

**P.s. For new discount rule - you need to create new categories**

Comment: Thanks for spending the time. But there is only one category in the store.

Comment: Create these categories. They will be hidden for everyone. They will exist only for your promotional purposes.