# how to simply sell couple of products?

Tags: bundled-product

Is there any method in magento can sell a product A ($30) and B ($30) in total price in $55? i had tried bundle product, but there is a drop-down, checkbox, multi-selection, radio-button something like that i must have to set, it forces customer to choose, but it is not need for my case.

i only need to sell a couple of product in single price, with "no selection", "no quantity box".

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe my post in this topic http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64718/apply-promotion-to-specific-configurable-product/64776#64776 can be helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you use the "checkbox" type with only one selection per option and make them "required" and don't allow user defined quantity, the user has no choice. Magento actually hides the checkbox and quantity input in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use catalogue price rules to set up a rule eg  If A and B apply $5 discount.

just google "magento discount rules" and you will find lots of guide for it.

Comment: this is not good idea because i want to create a product in frontend

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? (as my solution answers your original question as far as I can understand)